# ColdFusion = OnRequest Error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, application.cfc

Looking through the logs, we're getting hundreds of the following

```
"Error","jrpp-185","08/21/12","10:05:43","PATH","www.domain.com 
Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse) 
Error: An exception occurred when invoking a event handler method from Application.cfc. 
The method name is: onRequest.
```

They seem to be *mostly* search bots. The on place on APplication.cfc that I can see reference to the function is below

```
<cffunction name="onRequest" returnType="void">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" type="String" required=true/>
        <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes" requesttimeout="20">

        <cfparam name="url.refresh" default="0">
        <cfset request.strMember = Duplicate(session.strMember)/>

        <cfset request.tNow = GetTickCount()>
        <cfif url.refresh EQ 0>
            <cfset request.iCacheHr = 12/>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset request.iCacheHr = 0/>
        </cfif>

        <cflogin>
            <cfif IsDefined("session.strMember.sRoles")>
                <cfloginuser name="#session.strMember.sFirstName##session.strMember.sLastName#"
                    password="12345"
                    roles="#session.strMember.sRoles#"/>
            </cfif>
        </cflogin>

        <cfinclude template="core/incl/SessionLogger.cfm">
        <cfinclude template="core/incl/LinkTranslator.cfm">
        <cfinclude template="core/incl/udf.cfm">

        <cfinclude template="urlcheck.cfm"/>
        <cfinclude template="#Arguments.targetPage#">
    </cffunction>
```

From that, can anyone please advise on what's wrong and how to fix it? I'm fairly new to CF and this is making me pull out what little hair I have left

Comment: `Element XMLHOMEPAGE is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.`

Comment: Also `Element STRMEMBER is undefined in SESSION`

Comment: The second one - `Element STRMEMBER is undefined in SESSION` - is most likely causing your "Error: An exception occurred when invoking a event handler method from ..."  Probably the best approach would be to set it to empty string by default.

Comment: `<cffunction name="onSessionStart">
  <cfscript>
   session.strMember = StructNew();
   session.strMember.iMemberId = 0; 
   session.strMember.lSecurityLevels = "Guest";
  </cfscript>...` this is where/how its set

Comment: Ok, seems the error is pointing to `Element XMLZONE is undefined in REQUEST.` and the code is `<cfscript>
 variables.aZoneInfo = XmlSearch(application.xmlZones, "//zone[position() = 1]");
 try {
  request.xmlZone = ToString(variables.aZoneInfo[1]);
 } catch(any expt){
  variables.objZoneDAO = CreateObject("component", "#application.sComponentDir#ZoneDAO").init(application.sDSN);
  variables.objZoneDAO.Read(variables.objZone, 1);
 }
</cfscript>`. This only tends to happen for the occasional bots. The XML file is there and works for all users. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You use two different coding styles

```
    <cfparam name="url.refresh" default="0">
    <cfset request.strMember = Duplicate(session.strMember)/>
```

Invalid/left open XML tags in first line and valid (closed) XML tags in the second line.
Try to stick to one (preferably the last one).

2) You are using old way of checking variable being defined

```
IsDefined("session.strMember.sRoles")
```

read about newer (and better and faster)

```
StructKeyExists(session.strMember, "sRoles")
```

3) Most likely your code is calling

```
<cfloginuser ... >
```

at every page request

4) Make sure that paths for all includes are correct and they themselves don't have any errors.

Simplify your method until you stop getting an error and then investigate what exactly is causing it

Comment: I took this project over from a company who started it but didn't finish and then two subsequent non-CF developers (like myself) who modified it :-( I'll try what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, got rid of a few issues and the main one (out of a few) is `Element STRMEMBER is undefined in SESSION` primarily for search bots. The code in question that I think it's broken at is <cfset `request.strMember = Duplicate(session.strMember)`

Comment: Probably the best approach would be to set it to empty string by default

Answer (score 0):

Are the bots hitting a page that doesn't exist?

Maybe try changing the last line to:

```
<cfif fileExists(expandPath(Arguments.targetPage))>
    <cfinclude template="#Arguments.targetPage#">
<cfelse>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Comment: They exist `"Error","jrpp-684","08/22/12","20:53:50","08_VIRTUALFESTIVALS","www.virtualfestivals.com/index.cfm?CFTOKEN=14333196&CFID=117847977 Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp) Error: An exception occurred when invoking a event handler method from Application.cfc. The method name is: onRequest."`

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if we could see the actual error, maybe a try/catch inside that function that emails the details to you, or logs them..

Comment: The error is shown above - we capture it in the log file. We haven't yet been able to replicate it as a user, even with FF's user-agent switch plugin. Would posting the contents of application.cfc help?

Comment: try something like: <cffunction name="onRequest"><cftry>....<cfcatch><cfmail..><cfdump var="#cfcatch#"></cfmail></cftry></cffunction> ..pardon the messiness in the comment, hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Ok, seems the error is pointing to `Element XMLZONE is undefined in REQUEST.` and the code is `<cfscript>
 variables.aZoneInfo = XmlSearch(application.xmlZones, "//zone[position() = 1]");
 try {
  request.xmlZone = ToString(variables.aZoneInfo[1]);
 } catch(any expt){
  variables.objZoneDAO = CreateObject("component", "#application.sComponentDir#ZoneDAO").init(application.sDSN);
  variables.objZoneDAO.Read(variables.objZone, 1);
 }
</cfscript>`. This only tends to happen for the occasional bots. The XML file is there and works for all users. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could detect if they are a bot and server them something else? depends on how search friendly you want your site to be:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1083-ColdFusion-Session-Management-And-Spiders-Bots.htm